# Linux Performance Monitoring, any way to monitor per-thread?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance, perf

I am using Linux Ubuntu, and programming in C++. I have been able to access the  performance counters (instruction counts, cache misses etc) using perf_event (actually using programs from this link: https://github.com/castl/easyperf).

However, now I am running a multi-threaded application using pthreads, and need the instruction counts and cycles to completion of each thread separately. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Those profilers in the other question dont seem to use C++. They are tools like Valgrind that have substantial overhead.

Comment: You can try to change inherit flag in easyperf (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28871708 and man perf_event_open) and start it in the every pthread at start of the thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perf is a system profiling tool you can use. it's not like https://github.com/castl/easyperf), which is a library and you use it in your code. Following the steps and use it to profile your program:

1. Install `perf` on Ubuntu. The installation could be quite different in different Linux distribution. You can find out the installation tutorial line.
2. Simply run your program and get all thread id of your program:

   `ps -eLf | grep [application name]`
3. open separate terminal and run perf as `perf stat -t [threadid]` according to man page:

   `usage: perf stat [<options>] [<command>]`

   ```
   -e, --event <event>   event selector. use 'perf list' to list available events
   -i, --no-inherit      child tasks do not inherit counters
   -p, --pid <n>         stat events on existing process id
   -t, --tid <n>         stat events on existing thread id
   -a, --all-cpus        system-wide collection from all CPUs
   -c, --scale           scale/normalize counters
   -v, --verbose         be more verbose (show counter open errors, etc)
   -r, --repeat <n>      repeat command and print average + stddev (max: 100)
   -n, --null            null run - dont start any counters
   -B, --big-num         print large numbers with thousands' separators
   ```

there is an [analysis article](http://qqibrow.github.io/CPU-Cache-Effects-and-Linux-Perf/) about `perf`, you can get a feeling about it.

Comment: I am creating pthreads inside the main function. However, ps -eLf | grep [application name] gives me this output (shows only 1 thread):

18428 17539 18428  0    1 01:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep a.out

hence the threadid is also limited to 0 in this case. I think this command is giving the process id instead of the thread id

Comment: that shows your program terminated. The program showed there is grep, it isn't your program. Is your program running as a daemon?

Comment: my executable is a.out, so I ran ps -eLf | ./a.out and it just gave me the program output

Comment: run your program as `./a.out &` then do `ps -eLf | grep "a.out"`

Comment: ok i ran ./a.out & after which the program kept running even after giving the output, then i ran the second command which gave me this output:

maa13033 19215 18763 19215  0    1 01:49 pts/0    00:00:00 grep a.out
[1]+  Done                    ./a.out

Comment: if your program can terminate so fast why bother load balance?

Comment: is it a toy example or some production issue?

Comment: its a parametrized graph search program, i'm currently giving it small inputs.

Comment: make your program run 10+ minute. then do the same thing again. Or play with some toy example to learn `perf`, then profile the real program.

Comment: I actually ran the program with a million nodes, it didnt change the output. I'll look at this discussion and see what came of it. Thank you for your help.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.kernel/oQ4dcdWSPDw

Comment: @masab np. I will give it a try tmw. please vote up my question of you find it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, here is the link to my multithreaded program. You can change the number of threads to spawn by changing P just after start of the main, graph size is determined by the size of N just below it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtzdag3z6zfc4ew/cont_dijk_list.cc?dl=0

Comment: @masab sorry, testing other's program is not how stackoverflow works. you have to learn and test by yourself. I just confirmed that perf -t [threadid] works. In your case, first of all you have to make sure your program is CPU-bound. when you run `top`, if you see your program using 100%+ cpu. or a core is 100%+ utilization, then your program is CPU-bound. Otherwise, you just underestimate the machine power and waste your time now.

Comment: ok sorry, top gives the CPU utilization at about 150% when running 4 threads.
and it does work now thank you (however, it seems that the program should run for at least a minute).

but still the monitoring of threads is limited to monitoring one thread at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard tool to access `perf_event` - the `perf` (from linux-tools). It can work with all threads of your program and report summary profile and per-thread (per-pid/per-tid) profile.

This profile is not exact hardware counters, but rather result of sampling every N events, with N tuned to be reached around 99 Hz (times per second). You can also try `-c 2000000` option to get sample every 2 millions of hardware event. For example, cycles event (full list - `perf list` or try some listed in `perf stat ./program`)

```
perf record -e cycles -F 99 ./program
perf record -e cycles -c 2000000 ./program
```

Summary on all threads. `-n` will show you total number of samples

```
perf report -n
```

Per pid (actually tids are used here, so it will allow you to select any thread).

Text variant will list all threads recorded with summary sample count (with `-c 2000000` you can multiply sample count with 2 million to estimate hw event count for the thread)

```
perf report -n -s pid | cat
```

Or ncurses-like interactive variant where you can select any thread and see its own profile:

```
perf report -n -s pid
```

Comment: PPS: You can try to start easyperf monitoring several times: create new thread and then enable counting for this thread (call perf_init either in the new thread or in main thread with tid of new thread)... There is mna for perf_event_open http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html  but I don't understand how to set `inherit` flag for the call, it can be useful to hack into easyperf and change value of this flag...

Comment: PS: As I understand, `perf stat` with exact values of counters can't separate values between threads (https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat  "*By default, perf stat counts for all threads of the process and subsequent child processes and threads. This can be altered using the -i option. It is not possible to obtain a count breakdown per-thread or per-process.*") . It only has `--per-core` separation for system-wide monitoring `-a`; or monitoring of single process `-p pid` or single thread `-t tid`

Comment: masab, you should know that you can't set -c to very low numbers (less than several millions for frequent events like cycles or instructions or bit less for rare events like L3 miss) or -F to very high (more than several thousands); otherwise perf will limit frequency with message in `dmesg`.

Comment: Thanks!
I do still have a few questions:
1. when i open the perf.data file after generating it, using perf report -n, i see a lot of rows based on function calls, and i cant distinguish threads. So I cant say whether it even is monitoring threads separately. The link https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Open_file_limits however does say that that it does it on core granularity.
2. Where in the perf.data file can i find the counter statistics? Like for example instruction count, L3 misses etc.

Comment: Also, when I try perf report -n -s pid, it gives a segmentation fault. Is this possibly a bug?

Comment: masab, Yes, just `perf report -n` will sum profiling data from all threads, only "`-n -s pid`" will show it. Try to run `perf report -n -s pid | cat` this may work around the code path with segmentation fault. Tutorial says about `--per-core` mode, but this mode is available only on whole-system profiling, which can help you only if system has no other load and every your thread is binded to different cpu core. 2. No, perf.data have no counting information, it contain only samples. You may run several records with needed events and -c 5000000; then estimate events with sample counts.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the `perf` tool documentation [here](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial), it supports some of the events (eg: both `instructions` and `cache-misses`) that you're looking to profile. Extract from the wiki page linked above:

> The perf tool can be used to count events on a per-thread, per-process, per-cpu or system-wide basis. In per-thread mode, the counter only monitors the execution of a designated thread. When the thread is scheduled out, monitoring stops. When a thread migrated from one processor to another, counters are saved on the current processor and are restored on the new one.

Comment: I think the per thread mode means that only one thread can be monitored, which is the designated thread. The per process monitors the process and gives average statistics.

Comment: @masab yep. and what's your requirements?

Comment: @qqibrow If I have 2 threads running concurrently on 2 cores, then I would like to know how many instructions were executed on those two cores (which gives me 2 instruction counts). I want to see the instruction counts for each thread because I want to take care of load balancing amongst the threads.

Comment: @masab what's wrong with `perf`? you can monitor your two thread at the same time right?

Comment: @qqibrow well if thats possible, then any information (links etc) to a C/C++ implementation would be very helpful.